# Tablesort sort and search stops working when leave and page and return

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table

Tablesort sort and search functionality works fine when the page is first loaded but if you visit another page on the site and return to the page with tablesorter then the sort ad search functionality is completely gone.

[Here is a link to the page im talking about](http://sellingtweets.com/3/index.html)

Click on the 'one piece' link on the page and then the back link and you'll see the sort and search functionality disappear

Would appreciate some help on how to fix this problem because i cant seem to figure out why it does it.

Comment: It works fine for me. Clear the cache once and test it again

Comment: @TamilSelvan still doesn't work for me. Did you click on the 'one piece' link? the table on that page doesn't work and then if you click on the 'back' link the the top left the index page table doesn't work anymore

Comment: It works for me too... I only tested this in Chrome. Is there a specific browser where you're seeing this problem? Also, "tablesort" the code you are using is NOT the same as "tablesorter", they are two different plugins.